# Why changes in a CMS block doesn't appear?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, static-block, admin-panel

I have a quite simple problem which I can't address.
I've been changing **Static Blocks** from **CMS -> Static Blocks** (e.g. a Prices page).

Once I change the **Block** and save it, my website doesn't seem to update the page with the new changes.

Thanks a lot!

Carla

Comment: Clear magento cache and do index management

Answer (score 0):

Open your Magento admin panel and navigate to **System -> Cache Management** tab, check all Cache types and in the Actions box select **Refresh**, then, click Submit button.

So go to **System -> Index Management** and reindex all as well.

Answer (score 0):

**clear Magento cache**:

System >> Cache Management >> check all Cache types >> Refresh Cache.

**reindex all**:

System >> Index Management >> reindex all

If the block is not showing then **check Block Permission**:

1. System >> Permissions >> Blocks
2. Add New Block
3. Block Name: isfeatured/isfeatured (for example)
4. Is Allowed : Yes

For example: **Block call in cms page** ->

```
{{block type="**isfeatured/isfeatured**" template="isfeatured/featureblock.phtml"}}
```